# How to set different separator with \s in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, separator

text(After 1 is blank(space \t\f\v) ):

```
1    23.4,56
```

I want result of print $3 is 4.
But run
`echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[\\s+|,|.]' '{print $3}'`
, result is 56

Comment: Notice that `|` inside `[...]` matches a literal pipe character. You probably don't want that. See also [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which has notes about many common beginner problems.

Comment: BRE/ERE do not allow `\s` inside `[]` expressions.. you can use `perl` for ex: `perl -F'[.,\s]+' -lane 'print $F[2]'`

Comment: Weirdly, *some* Awk dialects do support `\s`; but it is definitely not portable.

Comment: @tripleee I know GNU awk supports `\s`, but not within `[]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want result of print $3 is 4.

Some changes to FS and your code can get it:

```
echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[,.]|[[:blank:]]+' '{print $3}'
4
```

Comment: OK, It's faster to use the \s. `echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[,.]|\\s+' '{print $3}'`

Comment: you can also use `[,.[:blank:]]+`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to tweak your FS. Several ways possible, this is one way:

```
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[ ,.]*' '{print $1}'
1
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[ ,.]*' '{print $2}'
23
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[ ,.]*' '{print $3}'
4
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[ ,.]*' '{print $4}'
56
```

Another way:

```
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[,.]|\\s+' '{print $3}'
4
```

Another way, this time locale-aware:

```
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[,.]|[[:space:]]+' '{print $3}'
4
$ echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[[:space:],.]+' '{print $3}'
4
```

With GNU `awk`, instead of using FS, you could use FPAT:

```
$ echo "1   23.4,56" | awk  'BEGIN { FPAT="[^ .,]+" }  { print $3 }'
4
```

The value of FPAT should be a string that provides a regular expression that describes the contents of each field. More information at: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: Can you use \s？

Comment: Yes, if you want to in GNU awk

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[.,]' '{print $2}'
```

OR as per your comments, you want to space in field separator then try following, we need to use `[[:space:]]` in here.

```
echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[[:space:]]+|[.,]+' '{print $3}'
```

OR

```
echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[:.,[:space:]]+' '{print $3}'
```

To see how field numbers and field values are, run following; for understanding purposes(for 1st solution).

```
echo "1    23.4,56" | awk -F'[.,]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "Field number:"i,"Field value:"$i}}'
Field number:1 Field value:1    23
Field number:2 Field value:4
Field number:3 Field value:56
```

Comment: Sorry, You misunderstand my question.

Comment: @Edward, This will print `4` I believe which you want to have in sample output, could you please explain what's not working here. I have posted how fields and their field value goes by too.

Comment: you can also use `[[:space:].,]+`